# GWT returns null in foreign function interface

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I have a div

```
<div id="aDiv"></div>
```

When I try

```
 Window.alert(RootPanel.get("aDiv").toString());
```

I get the element however, just after the above statement, when I

```
alert(document.getElementById("aDiv"));
```

It returns a null.

Can someone explain the discrepancies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GWT's javascript code is loaded into `iframe`, therefore `document` doesn't point to the actual root document. To access the root page in GWT's `native` methods, you should use `$doc` instead of `document` and `$wnd` instead of `window`.